# Decreasing Powder Size

Tags: everyday-chemistry

I have a small amount of a powder that is roughly 100 microns but I need to get it down to less than 10 microns. It is a small amount so I can't send it to any factory specializing in that as far as I know. In your opinion, what's the best way (cheapest) way to decrease the particle size (so far I've only been able to find coffeee grinders but it is unlikely they'll be able to get the particle size down to 10 microns) to less than 10 microns?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A [ball mill](http://www.glenmills.com/dry-milling/fine-grinding/planetary-ball-mill/planetary-ball-mill-pm200/) can get you to sub-micron particle size with a minimal capital investment - less than 500 USD on [eBay](http://www.ebay.com/itm/INDIAN-MADE-ball-mill-2-kg-Healthcare-Lab-Life-ScienceMedical-Equipment-/291789168856?_trksid=p2141725.m3641.l6368).